# Promise join add new function call to the chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to load and parse a file, but am having some trouble calling two functions and returning the result for the promise. I am using bluebird promises. The following code works as expected:

```
run = function (filePath) {
    return Promise.join(
        fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8')
            .then(parseFile.parse.bind(null, 'userKey')),
        users.getUsersAsync(usersObj)
            .then(users.modifyRec.bind(null, process.env.users))
    ).then(function (args) {
            return runProc('run', args[0], args[1]);
....
```

I have divided the `parseFile.parse` function into two methods, `parseFile.parse` and `parseFile.getProp`. `parseFile.getProp` should take the output from `parseFile.parse` and return what `parseFile.parse` returned before the method was split up. Here is my attempt to use both functions:

```
run = function (filePath) {
    return Promise.join(
        fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8')
            .then(parseFile.parse.bind(null, 'userKey'))
            .then(parseFile.getProp.bind(null,'key')),
        users.getUsersAsync(usersObj)
            .then(users.modifyRec.bind(null, process.env.users))
    ).then(function (args) {
            return runProc('run', args[0], args[1]);
....
```

but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

```
var ymlParser = require('yamljs');
var ymlObj;

parse = function ( data) {
    "use strict";
    if (!ymlObj) {
        ymlObj = ymlParser.parse(data);
    }
    return ymlObj;
};

getProcWeb = function () {
    return ymlObj.prop.web;
};

module.exports = {
    parse: parse,
    getProp: getProp
};
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting any errors, or does `args` have an unexpected value?

Comment: @ChrisHunt - the problem is that the getProp is called before the parse function ,this cause the issue...

Comment: Is `parse` synchronous, or does it return a promise that resolves to the proper value? Can you provide your `parseFile` code? Just doing a quick test with something like `Promise.resolve().then(function () { console.log("1"); }).then(function () { console.log("2"); });` shows that the first function should be running before the second, so it may not be the Promises themselves causing an issue.

Comment: @shopiaT: Your code looks fine (except for using `Promise.join` instead of `Promise.all`). More likely the mistake is in `parse` or `getProp`. Can you show us those functions, please?

Comment: @Bergi - sure in a min i'll update my post

Comment: @Bergi - Done, please ignore the key (userKey) since I dont think its so important in this case...lets assume I call to parse and then I want to get some object from it...

Comment: You mean `getProp`, not `getProcWeb`? Why are you passing `'userKey'` and `'key'` into those functions? Why do you use a global variable instead of letting `getProp` take a parameter?

Comment: I can assure you that `.then(parseFile.parse.bind(null, 'userKey')).then(parseFile.getProp.bind(null,'key')),` doesn't call `getProp` before `parse`. Maybe you're calling them from elsewhere as well? Or why do you think they're called in the wrong order, because `ymlObj` does not have the expected value?

Comment: @Bergi - As I mentioned please igonre the key I put a sample of the parser which should have the same problem

Comment: @Bergi - I Put BP and the parser is called after the getProp,how it can be? and yes you correct this should be getProp..

Comment: @Bergi- when I change it to promise all I got the right order but Im getting error [TypeError: expecting an array, a promise or a thenable ,what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post stack traces from the two BPs? Are you sure that's the only calls to those functions in your codebase? What is the (promise result) argument to `getProps` when it was called at first?

Comment: @shopiaT: It should be either `Promise.all([…, …]).then(function(arr) { … })` or `Promise.join(…, …, function(a, b) { … })`

Comment: @Bergi -not sure How to post the stack trace ...question if I change it to promise all do I need to change the syntax also? I think my syntax have to be changed

Comment: I have found instances where using the terse, `.bind` approach to the `then` functions has simply not worked (in my case it was the Express `res` object). Might be worth writing it out in long form.

Comment: @shopiaT: Just c&p the stack trace from your debugger at the BP, or alternatively insert `console.trace()` in the code.

Comment: @SimonH: In this case it should work, as the methods are there on `parseFile` and as long as they don't use `this` it doesn't matter they're bound to `null`

Comment: @Bergi- the promise all solved the issue please put it as answer and will mark it as solved,thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you know what `bind` is doing in your example? Assuming that all those functions take a single argument, you are removing any logic there.

Comment: @Bergi - Btw , how would you write the fileParser ,is it OK like I did method parse and specific method for every property? I know that this is a bit off topic but you already see this method :). thanks again!

Comment: @poke - with the bind I pass the this and the args to the function.

Comment: @shopiaT: Yes, splitting up parse and process (access?) stages in two functions is totally fine. That global `var ymlObj;` is a no-go though.

Comment: @Bergi - please answer this question I want to mark it as solved(the promise.all ) helped here 2. regard the no-go how you suggest to do that ,I know that this is a global but I need to share the instance for all the properties ,How I know that the parse was called ?otherwise I need to parse it in every function...Do you have any suggestion to write better?

Comment: Does
    parseFile.parse.bind(null, 'userKey')
return a promise?

Answer (score 1):

Promise.join won't return an array, in your case - args[].
Promise.all will return an array.

So in your case, you should either change your Promise.join syntax to

```
    Promise.join(
         fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8')
           .then(parseFile.parse.bind(null, 'userKey'))
           .then(parseFile.getProp.bind(null,'key')),
        users.getUsersAsync(usersObj)
           .then(users.modifyRec.bind(null, process.env.users))
       ,function(argsOne,argsTwo){
           return runProc('run', argsOne, argsTwo);
   }));
```

Or use Promise.all

```
   Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(args){
       return runProc('run', args[0], args[1]); 
   });
```